# JQuery trigger area events and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a HTML image map and I am using mapper.js to create onMouseOver effects. I want to make specific map areas (which has class "high") to trigger onMouseOver event when the page loads. Everything works fine except in Internet Explorer.

This is what I have so far.

**Javascript:**

```
function ready() {
    $("area").mouseleave(function() {
        $('.high').each(function(){
            $(this).trigger('mouseover');
        }); 
    });
    $('.high').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('mouseover');
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<body onload="ready();">
...
<map>
  <area id="Philippines" rel="Philippines" class="noborder iopacity100 icolorfff502 {if in_array("Philippines",$sal)} high {/if}" shape="poly" alt="Philippines" coords="367,308,367,301,364,301,363,295,365,292,360,293,357,291,356,287,356,282,354,281,351,273,354,274,353,268,353,262,360,263,363,266,365,271 />
</map>
...
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post a link or a fiddle?

Comment: Here it is: http://rastenis.lt/afrika/ .

Comment: Apart from the fact that you're including a script file `hrightinfo.js` that includes HTML everything
looks fine to me in IE9, but in Chrome 19 Morocco is always highlighted and only fades in/out when hovering in another country.
Correct that inclusion and see if it works

Comment: My bad with that hrightinfo.js file. What you see in Chrome it is exactly what I am trying to do. Some parts of map (which has class "high") should be always highlighted (Like in this case "Morocco").